# Using WHERE / AND in Joins

Tags: postgresql, join, query, data

Can someone elaborate on how the following two queries would provide different results?

That is, how the query is processed differently using WHERE or AND.

```
select
    orders.*,
    accounts.*
from
    orders
left join
    accounts
    on orders.account_id = accounts.account_id
where
    accounts.sales_rep_id = 321500;
```

```
select
    orders.*,
    accounts.*
from
    orders
left join
    accounts
    on orders.account_id = accounts.account_id
    and accounts.sales_rep_id = 321500;
```

Comment: I suggest you create a minimal example in a dbfiddle or similar. If it is something in particular that you dont understand, post the link to the fiddle

Answer (score 3):

As [Lennart](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/39278/lennart) has suggested, use a minimal example and see what happens.

```
create table accounts(account_id int primary key, sales_rep_id int);

create table orders(order_id int primary key, account_id int);

insert into accounts values
(1, 321500),
(2, null),
(3, 2000),
(4, 3000);

insert into orders values
(1, 1),
(2, 1),
(3, 2),
(4, 2),
(5, 2),
(6, 3);
```

There is a LEFT JOIN involved, that means it returns **always** all rows of orders table, plus those rows of accounts table with the same account_id. But, the WHERE clause filters final result to those with sales_rep_id = 321500.

```
order_id | account_id | account_id | sales_rep_id
-------: | ---------: | ---------: | -----------:
       1 |          1 |          1 |       321500
       2 |          1 |          1 |       321500
```

However the second query returns **all** rows of orders table, but only accounts with the same account_id and sales_rep_id = 321500.

```
order_id | account_id | account_id | sales_rep_id
-------: | ---------: | ---------: | -----------:
       1 |          1 |          1 |       321500
       2 |          1 |          1 |       321500
       3 |          2 |       null |         null
       4 |          2 |       null |         null
       5 |          2 |       null |         null
       6 |          3 |       null |         null
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=0dd9608b992673ba3f10b27d9228a25d)*